# How to hide thread view while debugging in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

i am new to debugging in Xcode, how can hide the view of thread to see my lines of execution in my program.
it is currently showing some stacks or threads which i don't want to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the left pane using `Cmd-0`. However you usually want to see the current thread and its backtrace when debugging.

Comment: thanks for yor answer @Ortwin Gentz, actually my problem was in Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Always show Dissassembly was to uncheck.